# How do I tell if a differentiation and its antiderivative is unique?

Tags: calculus

Given $f'(x)=\sin(x)+x, f(0)=2$ and $x$ is real.

Why are there no other functions with this property?

Comment: What property? You already define $f(x)$?

Comment: Proof read your question. As it stands, it is at least inconsistent leaning to incoherent.

Comment: I don't understand $f(0)=0$ and not $2$ ? More generally, I don't understand your question.

Comment: My guess is that's $f'(x)$ not $f(x)$ in the original question (edit now).

Comment: The answer is that your expression is in itself **a differential equation with initial value**, thus by Cauchy's theorem, it has a unique solution in a certain range, here $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

We have one solution $f:I \to \mathbb {R}$ given by $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}(x^2-2 \cos(x)) + 3$. We show this is the only solution.

Let $g$ be another function defined on $I$ with this property and define $h=g - f$. Then $h' = g' - f' = 0$, and this implies by the mean value theorem that $h$ is constant, that is, $h(x) = g(x) - f(x) = c$ for some constant $c$. By hypothesis, $g(0) - f(0) = 0$ and so $h$ is identically $0$.